# Symfony2: Editing (not-really-a-)ManyToMany association (with extra field)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a Domain Model of `Persons`s working in `Department`s at specific `Period`s of time:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Person {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Job", mappedBy="person")
     */
    private $jobs;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Job {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="jobs")
     */
    private $jobs;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Department")
     */
    private $department;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Period")
     */
    private $period;
}
```

If there were no `period` fields, that'd be a simple ManyToMany `Person` <=> `Department` association.
Symfony2 allows you to display it nicely into form with checkbox. You just checks `Department`s, and magic fills the intermediate table.

Now, in my app, admin selects the current period via login and `Period` instance is present as attribute of `Request`

And I want to display the exactly the same form with checkbox:

- It should display all departments
- Initial checks are for user's departments in current period
- On save it should not affect `Job`s with old periods

My current solution is to use an unmapped form and do all the work in controller:

```
public function editJobsAction(Request $request, Person $person, Period $period) {
    // departments are unmapped, so provide initial data
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create('jobs_edit', [
        'departments' => $person->getDepartmentsForYear($year),
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
        /** @var ArrayCollection $departments */
        $departments = $form->getData()['departments'];

        // remove Job objects that was unchecked

        // manually create and persist new Job objects

        $this->om->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('person_jobs', ['id' => $person->getId()]));
    }

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'person' => $person,
    ];
}
```

Form build:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('departments', 'entity', [
            'property' => 'title',
            'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Department',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('edit', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

It works as expected, but I still wonder if there's a cleaner and more Symfony-ish solution, such that' quite a regular task.